# How to prevent PaginationComponent in Angular 2 event to work?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

I'm using `pagination` component that comes from `ngx-bootstrap/pagination`. Like this:

```
<pagination *ngIf="returnedArray"
    [totalItems]="contentArray.length"
    (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"
    [itemsPerPage]="1"
    [boundaryLinks]="false"></pagination>
```

I want the pager to not navigate to the next page until some conditions are met, but can't find how to achieve that.

I tried several things:

1. Remove the `(pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"` from the `pagination` component. But navigation is still firing.
2. Tried to make something like `event.preventDefault()` but it doesn't exist here

Answer (score 0):

The `pageChange` is an EventEmitter, so you can execute a function when the user changed the page using the paginator. So it already changed the page at that moment.

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/pagination/pagination.component.ts) of the pagination component on GitHub, I see there is a `disabled` Input-option.
Maybe you can do something like:

```
<pagination *ngIf="returnedArray"
    [totalItems]="contentArray.length"
    (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"
    [disabled]="methodWithYourConditions()"
    [itemsPerPage]="1"
    [boundaryLinks]="false"></pagination>
```

Then the function you're referring to in this `disabled` attribute, can check for multiple conditions.

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. I thought you wanted to disable navigation until some conditions are met. I now get the impression that you're trying to do something else; whether or not to add attributes to the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve this was by hiding paginator component, and then, with a button, simulate the pagination click when conditions are met, like this:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('#next .pagination-next .page-link')).click();
```

Tricky... ugly... but worked :)